# Construction of a list of cons cells with variable content

Tags: emacs

I have a beginner question regarding “variable-expansion” while creating a quoted list.
Given the b/m code snippet, I want to set the variable content to hold the following list of cons cells `(("a" . "b") ("c" . "d"))`.

```lisp
(setq cvar "c")

;; Desperate try
(setq content '(("a" . "b")((symbol-value cvar) . "d"))
```

However, my problem is, that `cvar` does not get expanded, since the list is treated as it is. How can I achieve the intended result? Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html)

```
(setq content `(("a" . "b") (,cvar . "d"))
```

or

```
(setq content (list '("a" . "b") (cons cvar "d"))
```